# JPA EntityManager and query method combination No property found for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

So my problem is that I have an interface that implements JpaRepository and my custom interface that is implemented in another class that uses EntityManager for custom queries.

When I try to run the code I get the following exception:

`No property [custom methods name] found for type [Entity]`

My repository that I Autowire:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, FooCustomRepository {
}
```

The custom repository interface:

```
public interface FooCustomRepository {

    List<Foo> getFoos();

}
```

The implementation of the custom repository:

```
public class FooCustomRepositoryImpl implements FooCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        [query]
    }
}
```

I have not seen this error ever before, but I've been using custom repos this way.

Comment: My quick fix was adding @Repository for the custom repo implementation and autowireing the custom repo, but im curious why it stopped working or why did it break in like a blink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can not get bean in simple class.

If you need bean from spring, then need to make bean from simple class. From bean can get access to other bean.

Because, when you additional anotation `@Repository`, class `FooCustomRepositoryImpl` make to bean and find other beans.

I think, that code of class `FooCustomRepositoryImpl` need anotation `@Repository`

```
@Repository
public class FooCustomRepositoryImpl implements FooCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        [query]
    }
}
```

As described in the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories)

And example in [code](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-jpa-repo/src/main/java/com/baeldung/boot/daos) in class `CustomItemRepositoryImpl`

Comment: In this case don't I have to Autowire the FooCustomRepository? In the case I posted I only want to Autowire the FooRepository.

Comment: I understood you, and supplemented the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyOsetsky wouldn't it be also possible to use `@Configurable` of spring which allows you to inject / autowire to unmanaged objects? Sure you need the corresponding `aspect-j` dependencies. But wouldn't it be an alternative solution?

Comment: @Daniel Wosch If you know an alternative solution, please add it as an answer. What is the problem?)  I have not yet fully understood what you are talking about.